# Remove an object from any place in a multilevel list ( Bypass searching on graph algorithm )

Tags: c#, .net

**I have :** a list of items.
Each item in this list can have the own list with the same structure.
The depth of this list can be conditionally unlimited.

**I need :** Having The List of items IDs remove any items wherever it was without waste of plenty of time
I know how to implement searching on graph algorithm, I need a solution which will allow me to bypass a simple enumeration.

Item Structure looks like this, but its not final and i can change it if needed

```
public class NavigationPath
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<NavigationPath> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you need a separate structure that enables you to look up individual items faster.

Comment: Now I've trying to use EventHandler, something like... sign objects when they are created to the delete event (ID). If id == mine, then delete yourself.

But i have lack of experience with that kind of things

Comment: What does your list data structure look like, can you share the code? That will make it easier to answer.

Comment: Even if you use an event handler, internally it will have to loop everything. If you had a `Dictionary<thingToSearchFor, parentItem>` it might make it easier to locate individual items.

Comment: I've edited my Original post and added item class

Comment: Are the id's guaranteed to be unique across the structure? Is there any logic to their location? (given a structure, wanting to add an id, does it have "a spot" in the structure?).

In any case, as others suggested, a Dictionary or a SortedList might help with searching/deleting.

Comment: ID is not Unique, same item can appear in different places on different level with different children, and it is necessary to remove all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following method is the fastest for your given data structure. Add it to your class `NavigationPath`

```
public void Remove(int id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Childs.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Childs[i].Id == id)
        {
            Childs.RemoveAt(i);
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            Childs[i].Remove(id);
        }
    }
}
```

If speed of removal is that important then another idea is to use `LinkedList<>` instead of `List<>`, hence

```
public LinkedList<NavigationPath> Childs { get; set; }
```

And then code for removal would be

```
public void Remove(int id)
{
    var first = Childs.First;
    while (first != null)
    {
        var next = first.Next;
        if (first.Value.Id == id)
        {
            first.List.Remove(first);
        }
        else
        {
            first.Value.Remove(id);
        }
        first = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, sadly, but  I think there doesn't seem to be any "magic" that will allow me to bypass the enumeration.